# Custom email template, use user id. Magento 2.3.4

Tags: magento2, email, email-templates, custom-template, custom-variable

I want to use user id/name in custom emails, when i use `{{trans "% name," name = $ user.name}}` , i get empty field.

Do I have to create custom variables for this data?

Comment: Which template you want to use these variables, a new template or a template that already exists, can you give us more explanations?

Comment: Hi, i want to make a custom template "Forgot Admin Password" when I use the default text in my new template, I see that the link has no user id number.